# jquery - using it on an input field - can't get variable out of function so I can use it

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first time I try to use my jQuery lessons on a real web page, I find that the variable `guess` (inside the scope of this inner function) disappears as soon as the function completes.

This is normal javascript behavior, I suppose, but how does one usually grab hold of the variable so one can use it in other functions? My lessons never covered that.

I assumed that once `guess` was routed into the innerHTML of `#display`, it would stick. But it's even disappearing from there.

?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Game of the Century</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <LINK href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <LINK href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="application.js"></script>
    </HEAD>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='text' name = "input" id = "input"><br>
            <input type='submit' id="submit">
        </form>
        <p id = "display"></p>   
        <div>
            <img src="http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2403/rj1a.jpg" alt = "ad">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#submit').click( function() { 
              var guess = $('#input').val();
              $("#display").html(guess);
         });   

});
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?  Also, if your using jQuery why use document.getelementbyid?

Comment: Why don't you declare the variable outside the click's function scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely normal and it is not related to jQuery. Your `guess` variable is defined in a closure, anonymous function. So, it lives there and it is not accessible outside of that scope. If you want to use `guess` outside the click handler, just define it outside. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var guess;
    $('#submit').click( function() { 
        guess = $('#input').val();
        $("#display").html(guess);
    });   
    var anotherMethod = function() {
        alert(guess); // <--- it works
    }
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `document.getElementById` if you already include jQuery.

Edit: I just saw the html. There is another side effect of the code. Your form is actually submitting when you click the button. Try changing the `type="submit"` to `"type="button"` or some other way to prevent the form submitting.

Comment: Oops - I actually did have my guess variable pre-defined before I pasted my code here. It was the "submit" that was screwing things up. So with only one input field I probably don't even need the <form> section at all? A quick hint why "submit" was throwing away my data?

Comment: What it happens is that the form is submitted, which means that the page is reloaded. If you test on localhost that happens really fast.

Comment: so "submit" is beginning to sound like a method to avoid in modern web design? (looking for some rules of thumb)

Comment: If you use `type='submit'` inside a form it triggers the submitting. So, simply change it to `button`. There are some methods to prevent the default behavour -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 2):

Just here my solution with perhaps a better split of read/write tasks

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        getMyHtml = function() {
            return $('#input').val();
        }

        setMyHtml = function () {
            var s = getMyHtml();
            $("#display").html(s);
        }

        $('#submit').click(setMyHtml);
    });
```